# Can I make the indent utility leave my pointers alone?

Tags: indentation

I am formatting my code using the indent tool like so

```
>> indent stack.h
```

which replaces stack.h with an auto-formatted version of itself.  The content of my stack.h is:

```
void log_message(const char* message  );
```

after running indent I get

```
void log_message (const char *message);
```

I'd like to keep the asterisk next to the char (literally, I want to see "char* message").  Is there a flag to do that for indent?  I looked all through the documentation here https://www.gnu.org/software/indent/manual/indent.html#SEC_Top with no luck.

Comment: No idea if GNU `indent` can do that or not, but the style you want would be misleading at best.  When you write `char* i, j;`, only `i` is a pointer, `j` is not.